# How to connect android application to local domun

Tags: android, c++, sockets

I am using esp32 to bring up a tcp server. In order not to access this server by ip, I use mDNS on the esp32 side. I can successfully contact the tcp server from the PC at esp32.local. Now I want to do the same from android application. I wrote a little c ++ code which I run on android.

```
 int sockfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

    // socket create and varification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        hello ="socket creation failed...";
        return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
    }
    else

        hello="Socket successfully created..\n";
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    std::string url = "esp32.local";
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(url.c_str());
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    struct hostent *result;
    result = gethostbyname(url.c_str());
    //  destAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((in_addr*)hosten->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
    if (!result)
    {
        hello ="gethostbyname...";
        return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
    }

    // puts(result->h_name);
    memmove(&(servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr), result->h_addr, result->h_length);

    // connect the client socket to server socket
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        hello="connection with the server failed..";
        return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
    }
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n");

    // function for chat
    char buff = 0xA;
    write(sockfd, &buff, sizeof(buff));

    // close the socket
    close(sockfd);
```

When trying to connect from android application, I get an error in function gethostbyname. . What do I need to do to access the .local domain?

Answer (score 0):

> ```cpp
> std::string url = "esp32.local";
> servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(url.c_str());
> ```

`inet_addr()` does not support parsing hostnames like `"sp32.local"`, only IP addresses.  You need to use `gethostbyname()` or better `getaddrinfo()` instead.

> ```cpp
> struct hostent *result;
> result = gethostbyname(url.c_str());
> ...
> memmove(&(servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr), result->h_addr, result->h_length);
> ```

You are not copying the result of `gethostbyname()` into the `sin_addr.s_addr` correctly.  Your commented-out code was doing it correctly:

```cpp
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((in_addr*)(hosten->h_addr_list[0]))->s_addr;
```

Which can be simplified to:

```cpp
servaddr.sin_addr = *(in_addr*)(hosten->h_addr_list[0]);
```

Or just:

```cpp
servaddr.sin_addr = *(in_addr*)(hosten->h_addr);
```

But, `getaddrinfo()` would be easier to use than populating a `sockaddr_in` manually.  And it supports IPv6, whereas `gethostbyname()` only supports IPv4:

```cpp
std::string url = "esp32.local";
int sockfd = -1;

addrinfo hints = {};
addrinfo *result;

hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // AF_UNSPEC
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// assign IP, PORT
int res = getaddrinfo(url.c_str(), "1234", &hints, &result);
if (res != 0) {
    return env->NewStringUTF("getaddrinfo failed...");
}

for(addrinfo *addr = result; addr; addr = addr->ai_next) {
    // socket create and varification
    sockfd = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        continue;
    }

    // connect the client socket to server socket
    if (connect(sockfd, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) != 0) {
        close(sockfd);
        sockfd = -1;
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

if (sockfd == -1) {
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return env->NewStringUTF("socket creation/connect failed...");
}

freeaddrinfo(result);
printf("Connected to the server..\n");

// function for chat
char buff = 0xA;
write(sockfd, &buff, sizeof(buff));

// close the socket
close(sockfd);
```

Comment: this does not work. I get error eai_nodats in function getaddrinfo

Comment: Then, most likely, Android simply doesn't know how to resolve `esp32.local`.  You might have to implement the necessary mDNS query yourself in your own code.